# REGEX, separar numero de cadena con mas numeros y simbolos

Tags: javascript, regex, autohotkey

Estimados como están? Necesito ayuda con formula de REGEX
Necesito que por ejemplo (el texto entre comillas, inclusive el salto de línea)

"4-9991930:7
JUAREZ JUAN MARCELO"

**quede de la siguiente manera**

"99919930"

Osea que quite todos los caracteres del principio inclusive el "-" y el caracter ":" y todos los caracteres siguiente. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido TOVAL SEGUROS a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes solucionarlo con el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
let texto=`"4-9991930:7 JUAREZ JUAN MARCELO"`;
let regex=/-(\d+):/

let m = regex.exec(texto);
console.log(m[1]);
```

La idea es:

- Obtienes los número que están entre el guión (-) y los dos puntos (:)
- Muestras el resultado de la coincidencia del grupo.

Es un ejemplo muy básico sin ningún tipo de validación de si se han encontrado resultados ni nada similar (eso te lo dejo para tí).

Comment: Procura no responder a preguntas en donde el OP no haya demostrado sus intentos por resolver su planteamiento. Lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_.